# conwert object which contains strings with utf-8 to string with proper coding

Tags: java, string, object, utf-8, type-conversion

I'm processing MMS and got it text part as :

```
mmsBodyPart.getContent();
```

it's simpy Object.  Now i need to convert it to String using utf-8. I have tried:

```
String contentText = (String) mmsBodyPart.getContent();
```

but it doesn't works with specyfics characters and some strange chars appear. 
Also i tried :

```
String content = new String(contentText.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));
```

not a mystery that also failed.

How that can be done ?

EDIT: Problem was caused by bad encoding in file. Nothing wrong was in code, ya didn't thought about it in first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Strings` haven't an Encoding in Java. If you need one, you should use `byte[]` with Encoding to get a String